# How do I reinstall ubuntu with ubuntu?

Tags: boot, uefi

So I installed ubuntu without any dual boot it's just ubuntu and now I want to reinstall it but when I try to boot my usb it loads grub and I'm clueless about how to boot using grub console, I tried to google it and tried some commands

```
ls 
set root=(hd1,gpt2)
chainloader /efi/boot/grubx64.efi
after this line it show invalid signature
```

What do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to boot from a USB drive and are encountering the GRUB console, it sounds like the boot order in your computer's BIOS or UEFI settings is not set to prioritize the USB drive.

To fix this, you will need to restart your computer and enter the BIOS or UEFI settings by pressing a key (often Del, F1, F2, or Esc) during the boot process. Once you are in the BIOS or UEFI settings, look for an option that allows you to change the boot order and make sure that the USB drive is set as the first boot option. Save your changes and restart your computer. This should allow you to boot from the USB drive and reinstall Ubuntu.

If you are still having trouble, you can try using the `ls' command in the GRUB console to see what options are available to you. For example, you can try using ls` (hdX,gptY)` to see what partitions are available on the Xth hard drive, where X is the number of the hard drive and Y is the partition number. You may need to experiment with different values for X and Y to find the correct partition that contains the Ubuntu installation.

Once you have found the correct partition, you can try using the `set root` and `chainloader` commands as you did before, but with the correct values for the hard drive and partition. For example, if the correct partition is `(hd1,gpt2)`, you would use the following commands:

```
set root=(hd1,gpt2)
chainloader /efi/boot/grubx64.efi
```

After running these commands, you should be able to boot from the USB drive and reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: It still shows invalid signature  . And I tried to enter in UEFI but I couldn't it still ends up in grub